# Iterating in ModelBuilder combining different fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I want to use 2 fields of my shapefile to work with in my modelbuilder. One field is the `Category`, that comprises up to 10 different categories of environmental quality and another is the `Season`, that comprises the 4 seasons of the year.

I want to use model builder to iterate between my fields to generate different shapefiles with the following output:

```
SHP1: Category1_Summer
SHP2: Category1_Winter
SHP3: Category1_Fall
SHP4: Category1_Spring
SHP5: Category2_Summer
...
```

To do that I'm using Select and Copy tool. But how to use the iterator in order to combine the two fields? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

An iterator will loop over ONE field only. So the solution to your problem is to create a field with all the unique values that you want to loop over. You can prepare your dataset by adding a new field and using the Calculate Field tool to concatenate the values in your 2 other fields, then point the iterator to your new field.